# What tends to be the opinion on Heidegger's analysis of Greek philosophy?

Tags: heidegger, greeks

What tends to be the opinion on Heidegger's analysis of Greek philosophy? What do experts in the (classical) history of philosophy make of his statements about ancient Greek philosophy?

Comment: "*For the professional classicist, there is almost nothing at all of interest in Heidegger’s work on Greek philosophy and poetry... What is interesting about Heidegger’s Greeks is not that they are Greeks, but that they are Germans and that they are Heidegger’s*", [Most, Heidegger's Greeks](https://www.bu.edu/arion/files/2010/03/Greeks-Most.pdf).

Comment: thanks @Conifold relevant ending is "What distinguishes Heidegger... is the passionate intensity of his absorption in the ancient Greek texts and his ability to communicate  this  intensity  to  many  readers,  especially  to  those with  little  or  no  knowledge  of  ancient  Greek  themselves....The Greeks will probably  survive  Heidegger,  as  they  have  so  much  else.  And  if they do, that will be partly his merit." [i.e. no harm done really?]

Comment: I like Heidegger's view on the loss of Unity from Western thought, which he blames on the Greeks. Just this single point seems important, but generally I couldn't comment on his analysis. We're so dependent on Diogenes Laertius that nobody can quite be confident in their opinions of the Greeks or to what extent Heidegger is right or wrong about them. . .

Comment: I wish that Heidegger had been clearer in contrasting Platonism with Presocratic thought. He talks a bit about the presocratics in his early work but seems somewhat timid in doing this and continually invokes Nietzeche rather than dealing with the classical texts directly.